# awk: bailing out at source line 1

Tags: macos, awk, terminal-color

I'm looking to get some colorized log output and don't want to use multitail.

The command I'm trying to execute is:

```
tail -100f some_file.log | awk '/INFO/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"} /Exception/ {print "\033[31m" $0"\033[39m"}'
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> /INFO <<< / {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"} /Exception/ {print "\033[31m" $0"\033[39m"}
    4 missing ]'s
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

My totally non-expert guess is that for some reason it thinks the terminal codes should have closing `]'s` on them.  I've tried escaping them but that doesn't work and frankly, I'm not sure that this wouldn't jack up the terminal codes.

Comment: Did you cut-and-paste or did you re-type that command?

Comment: Works fine on ubuntu-bash-mawk. What terminal are you using?

Comment: Works fine for me also.

Comment: it was a direct copy and paste from here:  https://gist.github.com/kartikshah/1855924

Comment: @NathanWilson using iTerm on OSX, but I'm nearly certain that's not it.

Comment: i also get the same error from this script:  https://radu.cotescu.com/coloured-log-outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing and switching to `gawk` fixed the issue.  Thanks to everyone who had helpful replies.

Answer (score 3):

> awk: bailing out at source line 1

If you are on a `Solaris/SunOS` system, change `awk` at the start of this script to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`

Answer (score 0):

From ***[Effective Awk Programming, Edition 4](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)***:

> **A Rose by Any Other Name** The awk language has evolved over the years. Full details are provided in Appendix A [The Evolution of the
>   awk Language], page 439. The language described in this book is often
>   referred to as "new awk." By analogy, the original version of awk is
>   referred to as "old awk."
>
> On most current systems, when you run the
>   awk utility you get some version of new awk.<sup>4</sup> If your system’s
>   standard awk is the old one, you will see something like this if you
>   try the test program:
>
> ```
> $ awk 1 /dev/null
> error awk: syntax error near line 1
> error awk: bailing out near line 1
> ```
>
> In this case, you
>   should find a version of new awk, or just install gawk!
>
> Throughout
>   this book, whenever we refer to a language feature that should be
>   available in any complete implementation of POSIX awk, we simply use
>   the term awk. When referring to a feature that is specific to the GNU
>   implementation, we use the term gawk.
>
> <sup>4</sup> Only Solaris systems still use an old awk for > the default awk utility. A more modern awk lives in `/usr/xpg6/bin` on these systems.

<sup>This answer has been moved from [Serching a pattern using awk and print next 15 lines from a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657261)</sup>