# Searching a pattern using awk and print next 15 lines from a log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Searching a pattern using awk and print next 15 lines from a log file

`awk '/^DERAT1SB[0-9][0-9]# show registration/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+4]}; NR in nr' slb.log`

I am using above command to search a pattern `DERAT1SB23# show registration` inside a log file, but it is throwing a syntax error.

ERROR:

`awk: syntax error near line 1`

`awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: You're using old, broken awk. Google it. There are other issues too which you can investigate after that.

Comment: Can you please show us snippets of the log file you're trying to search? That might help you get a better answer. Also, if you're trying to get the next 15 lines, I'd just use grep to search for what you need and then use the -A flag to specify the number of lines you need after the search string (e.g. `grep $str filename -A $lineNum`)

Comment: you are using an old version of `awk` where the word old should be replace with antiquated. You will get the same error when you do `awk 1 /dev/null`. Nonetheless, the problem is most likely located in the `#` which you might want to escape.

Comment: @kvantour there's nothing special about a # in a regexp.

Comment: @EdMorton I know, but  you never know with old versions of AWK.

Comment: True but as in the example you posted old, broken awk can't handle a condition without an explicit action so now look at the last part of the OPs script :-).

Comment: How about `grep -A15 pattern file`?

Comment: systems that have the [old]awk, as shown in your error message, usually have a `nawk` that will give you much better error messages. Also check if you have `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` as that an even newer version. Finally, pray that your system has `gawk` installed. It will be in a different directory and it may be named as `awk`, so you'll have to ask around your organization to see where the GNU versions are kept. Maybe that is standardized now, but for the 4 places I worked, there where 5 different dirs for `gawk` ;-). Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton, I seem to be unable to fix it. Nor with brackets nor with whatever. `awk '(NR in nr){print $0}' /dev/null` gives exactly the same problem.

Comment: Its entirely possible that old awk doesn't have an `in` operator or doesn't allow use of the `in` operator in that context. idk.

Comment: @EdMorton so far I only found for loops which work. If statements fail.

Comment: Yeah I vaguely remember now that that was the case.

Comment: @Mark Setchell, i can't use grep -A as it's not supported in Solaris.

Comment: Guys below is the sample log ,

Comment: I think there’s a proper `grep` in `/usr/xpg4/bin` or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

Search for a pattern and print next 15 lines: using GNU sed

```
sed -n '/pattern/,+15 p' file
```

With plain awk:

```
awk '
    /pattern/ {
        print
        for (i=1; i<=15; i++) {getline; print}
        exit
    }
' file
```

Comment: ITYM `awk '/regexp/{c=16}c&&c--' file` or similar. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for more examples of printing lines around a match and see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for the issues with using getline.

Answer (score 0):

> awk: bailing out near line 1

Is a known issue and you should change in your code on a Solaris/SunOS system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`

Comment: `nawk` is inferior to xpg awk (missing functionality so not as close to POSIX compliant) so there's no reason to suggest using nawk on any system that  has either xpg awk available.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure in some SUN os since I have not seen `nawk` so thought which ever is present on OP's system he/she could use it then.

Comment: AFAIK every SUN/Solaris has both and the only reason to use nawk is to keep using old nawk scripts which would break on a POSIX awk.

Answer (score 0):

From ***[Effective Awk Programming, Edition 4](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)***:

> **A Rose by Any Other Name** The awk language has evolved over the years. Full details are provided in Appendix A [The Evolution of the
>   awk Language], page 439. The language described in this book is often
>   referred to as "new awk." By analogy, the original version of awk is
>   referred to as "old awk."
>
> On most current systems, when you run the
>   awk utility you get some version of new awk.<sup>4</sup> If your system’s
>   standard awk is the old one, you will see something like this if you
>   try the test program:
>
> ```
> $ awk 1 /dev/null
> error awk: syntax error near line 1
> error awk: bailing out near line 1
> ```
>
> In this case, you
>   should find a version of new awk, or just install gawk!
>
> Throughout
>   this book, whenever we refer to a language feature that should be
>   available in any complete implementation of POSIX awk, we simply use
>   the term awk. When referring to a feature that is specific to the GNU
>   implementation, we use the term gawk.
>
> <sup>4</sup> Only Solaris systems still use an old awk for > the default awk utility. A more modern awk lives in `/usr/xpg6/bin` on these systems.